# Combine EncodeAndMux with HelloEffects in Android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am trying to create a video with a series of images using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer.  I want to also apply an Effect on each Bitmap before the encoding.

The video gets created with the correct duration but the output is only black screen.

I have been looking at the [EncodeAndMux](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt) example at bigflake.com (Modified the `generateFrame()` and added a shared context when creating the `CodecInputSurface` )

and the HelloEffects from Google to setup the EffectFactory.

My idea was to create 2 EGLContexts - one for rendering the effect and one for the MediaCodec(encoder) and swapping the buffers

I am new to OpenGl and Android so please tell me if I am going about this the wrong way. Any help with helping me understand what the problem is would be greatly appreciated

Here is my code :

public class WriteMovieActivity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = "WRITE MOVIE";
private static final File OUTPUT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

private int BPM;
private int numberOfPhotos;
private List durations;
private int durationInSec;
private Cursor mCursor;
private MyApplication mApp;
private String filterName;
private String size;
private int firstImageIndex;
private int lastImageIndex;
private String albumName;
private String orientation;
private int[] imageIDs;

private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";    // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
private static final int FRAME_RATE = 10;               // 10fps
private static final int IFRAME_INTERVAL = 5;           // 5 seconds between I-frames
private ImageLoader loader;
private CodecInputSurface mInputSurface;
private MediaMuxer mMuxer;
private MediaCodec mEncoder;
private MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo;
private int mBitRate = -1;
private int mTrackIndex;
private boolean mMuxerStarted;

private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;
private int mImageWidth;
private int mImageHeight;

private DisplayImageOptions options;
private long presentationTime;
private long durationInNanosec;

private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
private int texId = -1;
private EffectContext mEffectcontext;
private Effect mEffect;
private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();

private GLEnv mEnv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_movie);

    mApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();

    firstImageIndex = mApp.getFirstImageIndex();
    lastImageIndex = mApp.getLastImageIndex();
    numberOfPhotos = lastImageIndex - firstImageIndex +1 ;
    Log.v(TAG,"FirstImage " + firstImageIndex +"------ lastImage "+ lastImageIndex );

    albumName = mApp.getAlbumName();
    filterName = mApp.getFilter();
    size = mApp.getSize();
    orientation = mApp.getOrientation();

    loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();


    if (size == "small") {
        mBitRate = 1000000;
        if (orientation == "portrait") {
            mWidth = 144;
            mHeight = 176;
        } else {
            mWidth = 176;
            mHeight = 144;
        }
    } else if (size == "default") {
        mBitRate = 2000000;
        if (orientation == "portrait") {
            mWidth = 240;
            mHeight = 320;
        } else {
            mWidth = 320;
            mHeight = 240;
        }
    } else {
        mBitRate = 6000000;
        if (orientation == "portrait") {
            mWidth = 720;
            mHeight = 1280;
        } else {
            mWidth = 1280;
            mHeight = 720;
        }
    }

    //Get the image ids for bucket
    imageIDs = getImagesFromBucket(albumName);

    BitmapFactory.Options resizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    resizeOptions.inSampleSize = 1; // decrease size 1 time
    resizeOptions.inScaled = true;

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .decodingOptions(resizeOptions)
            .postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Bitmap process(Bitmap bmp) {

                    return scaleBitmap(bmp);
                }
            })
            .build();


    BPM = Math.round(mApp.getBPM());

    durationInSec = mApp.getDuration();
    if (durationInSec == 0) {
        //TODO: Get the duration of the song
    }

    durations = getDurationsArray(durationInSec);

    mEnv = new GLEnv();
    mEnv.makeCurrent();
    mEffectcontext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
    mTexRenderer.init();



}

private Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();

    //Log.v("Pictures", "Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);

    if (width > height) {
        // landscape
        float ratio = (float) width / mWidth;
        width = mWidth;
        height = (int)(height / ratio);
    } else if (height > width) {
        // portrait
        float ratio = (float) height / mHeight;
        height = mHeight;
        width = (int)(width / ratio);
    } else {
        // square
        height = mHeight;
        width = mWidth;
    }

    //Log.v("Pictures", "after scaling Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);

    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);
    return bm;
}


public void createMovie(View view) throws  Throwable {

    Log.v(TAG,"CREATING MOVIE");


    try {
        prepareEncoder();

        presentationTime = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = firstImageIndex ; i <= lastImageIndex; i++) {

            drainEncoder(false);

            generateSurfaceFrame(i);

            mInputSurface.setPresentationTime(presentationTime);

            Log.v(TAG,"sending frame " + i + " to encoder");
            mInputSurface.swapBuffers();

            //Convert frame duration from milliseconds to nanoseconds
            durationInNanosec = (long)((float)durations.get(j) * 1000000);

            presentationTime += durationInNanosec;
            j++;


        }
        drainEncoder(true);

    } catch(Throwable e) {
        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
    } finally {
        // release encoder, muxer, and input Surface
        releaseEncoder();
        Log.v(TAG,"VIDEO CREATED");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video Created!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void generateSurfaceFrame(int frameIndex) {

    mEnv.makeCurrent();

    if (texId >= 0){
        mEnv.releaseTexture(texId);
    }
    int imageID = imageIDs[frameIndex];
    Uri imageURI = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID);
    texId = loadTextures(loader.loadImageSync(imageURI.toString()));
    initAndApplyEffect();
    renderResult();

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    ByteBuffer pixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mImageWidth * mImageHeight * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    mEnv.checkForEGLErrors("store Pixels");


    mInputSurface.makeCurrent();


}

private void initAndApplyEffect()
{
    EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectcontext.getFactory();
    if (mEffect != null)
    {
        mEffect.release();
    }
    mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
    mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
    mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mWidth, mHeight, mTextures[1]);

}

private int loadTextures(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    // Generate textures
    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);

    mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);


    // Upload to texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Set texture parameters
    GLToolbox.initTexParams();

    return mTextures[0];
}

private void renderResult()
{
    mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
    //mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
}

private void prepareEncoder() {
    mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mWidth, mHeight);

    // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
    // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, mBitRate);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
    format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL);
    Log.v(TAG, "format: " + format);

    // Create a MediaCodec encoder, and configure it with our format.  Get a Surface
    // we can use for input and wrap it with a class that handles the EGL work.
    //
    // If you want to have two EGL contexts -- one for display, one for recording --
    // you will likely want to defer instantiation of CodecInputSurface until after the
    // "display" EGL context is created, then modify the eglCreateContext call to
    // take eglGetCurrentContext() as the share_context argument.
    try {
        mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME_TYPE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
    mInputSurface = new CodecInputSurface(mEncoder.createInputSurface());
    mEncoder.start();

    // Output filename.  Ideally this would use Context.getFilesDir() rather than a
    // hard-coded output directory.
    String outputPath = new File(OUTPUT_DIR,
            "test." + mWidth + "x" + mHeight + ".mp4").toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "output file is " + outputPath);


    // Create a MediaMuxer.  We can't add the video track and start() the muxer here,
    // because our MediaFormat doesn't have the Magic Goodies.  These can only be
    // obtained from the encoder after it has started processing data.
    //
    // We're not actually interested in multiplexing audio.  We just want to convert
    // the raw H.264 elementary stream we get from MediaCodec into a .mp4 file.
    try {
        mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new RuntimeException("MediaMuxer creation failed", ioe);
    }

    mTrackIndex = -1;
    mMuxerStarted = false;
}

private void releaseEncoder() {
    Log.v(TAG, "releasing encoder objects");
    if (mEncoder != null) {
        mEncoder.stop();
        mEncoder.release();
        mEncoder = null;
    }
    if (mInputSurface != null) {
        mInputSurface.release();
        mInputSurface = null;
    }
    if (mMuxer != null) {
        mMuxer.stop();
        mMuxer.release();
        mMuxer = null;
    }
}

private void drainEncoder(boolean endOfStream) {
    final int TIMEOUT_USEC = 10000;
    Log.v(TAG, "drainEncoder(" + endOfStream + ")");

    if (endOfStream) {
        Log.v(TAG, "sending EOS to encoder");
        mEncoder.signalEndOfInputStream();
    }

    ByteBuffer[] encoderOutputBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
    while (true) {
        int encoderStatus = mEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            // no output available yet
            if (!endOfStream) {
                break;      // out of while
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "no output available, spinning to await EOS");
            }
        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            // not expected for an encoder
            encoderOutputBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
        } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            // should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once
            if (mMuxerStarted) {
                throw new RuntimeException("format changed twice");
            }
            MediaFormat newFormat = mEncoder.getOutputFormat();
            Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + newFormat);

            // now that we have the Magic Goodies, start the muxer
            mTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
            mMuxer.start();
            mMuxerStarted = true;
        } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
            Log.w(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " +
                    encoderStatus);
            // let's ignore it
        } else {
            ByteBuffer encodedData = encoderOutputBuffers[encoderStatus];
            if (encodedData == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus +
                        " was null");
            }

            if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                // The codec config data was pulled out and fed to the muxer when we got
                // the INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  Ignore it.
                Log.v(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG");
                mBufferInfo.size = 0;
            }

            if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                if (!mMuxerStarted) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("muxer hasn't started");
                }

                // adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo (not needed?)
                encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);

                mMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);
                Log.v(TAG, "sent " + mBufferInfo.size + " bytes to muxer");
            }

            mEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);

            if ((mBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                if (!endOfStream) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "reached end of stream unexpectedly");
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "end of stream reached");
                }
                break;      // out of while
            }
        }
    }
}

private static class CodecInputSurface {
    private static final int EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID = 0x3142;

    private EGLDisplay mEGLDisplay = EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY;
    private EGLContext mEGLContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
    private EGLSurface mEGLSurface = EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE;

    private Surface mSurface;

    /**
     * Creates a CodecInputSurface from a Surface.
     */
    public CodecInputSurface(Surface surface) {
        if (surface == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        mSurface = surface;

        eglSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Prepares EGL.  We want a GLES 2.0 context and a surface that supports recording.
     */
    private void eglSetup() {
        mEGLDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        if (mEGLDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to get EGL14 display");
        }
        int[] version = new int[2];
        if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(mEGLDisplay, version, 0, version, 1)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to initialize EGL14");
        }

        // Configure EGL for recording and OpenGL ES 2.0.
        int[] attribList = {
                EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };
        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[1];
        int[] numConfigs = new int[1];
        EGL14.eglChooseConfig(mEGLDisplay, attribList, 0, configs, 0, configs.length,
                numConfigs, 0);
        checkEglError("eglCreateContext RGB888+recordable ES2");

        // Configure context for OpenGL ES 2.0.
        int[] attrib_list = {
                EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };
        mEGLContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(mEGLDisplay, configs[0], EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext(),
                attrib_list, 0);
        checkEglError("eglCreateContext");

        // Create a window surface, and attach it to the Surface we received.
        int[] surfaceAttribs = {
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };
        mEGLSurface = EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(mEGLDisplay, configs[0], mSurface,
                surfaceAttribs, 0);
        checkEglError("eglCreateWindowSurface");
    }

    /**
     * Discards all resources held by this class, notably the EGL context.  Also releases the
     * Surface that was passed to our constructor.
     */
    public void release() {
        if (mEGLDisplay != EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE,
                    EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT);
            EGL14.eglDestroySurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
            EGL14.eglDestroyContext(mEGLDisplay, mEGLContext);
            EGL14.eglReleaseThread();
            EGL14.eglTerminate(mEGLDisplay);
        }

        mSurface.release();

        mEGLDisplay = EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY;
        mEGLContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
        mEGLSurface = EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE;

        mSurface = null;
    }

    /**
     * Makes our EGL context and surface current.
     */
    public void makeCurrent() {
        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, mEGLSurface, mEGLContext);
        checkEglError("eglMakeCurrent");
    }

    /**
     * Calls eglSwapBuffers.  Use this to "publish" the current frame.
     */
    public boolean swapBuffers() {
        boolean result = EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface);
        checkEglError("eglSwapBuffers");
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the presentation time stamp to EGL.  Time is expressed in nanoseconds.
     */
    public void setPresentationTime(long nsecs) {
        EGLExt.eglPresentationTimeANDROID(mEGLDisplay, mEGLSurface, nsecs);
        checkEglError("eglPresentationTimeANDROID");
    }

    /**
     * Checks for EGL errors.  Throws an exception if one is found.
     */
    private void checkEglError(String msg) {
        int error;
        if ((error = EGL14.eglGetError()) != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS) {
            throw new RuntimeException(msg + ": EGL error: 0x" + Integer.toHexString(error));
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is the logcat:

```
05-06 17:27:19.871  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ drainEncoder(false)
05-06 17:27:19.876  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ sent 10 bytes to muxer
05-06 17:27:19.926  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51250K, 55% free 24821K/54524K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
05-06 17:27:20.011  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 62.052MB for 38340880-byte allocation
05-06 17:27:20.021  17114-17124/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 33% free 62263K/91968K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-06 17:27:20.286  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 33% free 62215K/91968K, paused 9ms, total 10ms
05-06 17:27:20.336  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 87.003MB for 26211856-byte allocation
05-06 17:27:20.346  17114-17124/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 26% free 87813K/117568K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-06 17:27:20.491  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37454K, 58% free 50370K/117568K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-06 17:27:20.506  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 75.435MB for 26211856-byte allocation
05-06 17:27:20.521  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 36% free 75967K/117568K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-06 17:27:20.521  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ sending frame 58 to encoder
05-06 17:27:20.521  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ drainEncoder(true)
05-06 17:27:20.521  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ sending EOS to encoder
05-06 17:27:20.526  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ sent 10 bytes to muxer
05-06 17:27:20.531  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ end of stream reached
05-06 17:27:20.531  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ releasing encoder objects
05-06 17:27:20.531  17114-17709/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] Now Executing->Idle
05-06 17:27:20.541  17114-17709/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] Now Idle->Loaded
05-06 17:27:20.541  17114-17709/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] Now Loaded
05-06 17:27:20.541  17114-17709/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/ACodec﹕ [OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder] Now uninitialized
05-06 17:27:20.546  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Stopping Video track
05-06 17:27:20.546  17114-17724/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/MPEG4Writer﹕ Received total/0-length (59/0) buffers and encoded 59 frames. - video
05-06 17:27:20.546  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Stopping Video track source
05-06 17:27:20.546  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Video track stopped
05-06 17:27:20.546  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Stopping writer thread
05-06 17:27:20.546  17114-17723/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ 0 chunks are written in the last batch
05-06 17:27:20.546  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Writer thread stopped
05-06 17:27:20.551  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication I/MPEG4Writer﹕ The mp4 file will not be streamable.
05-06 17:27:20.551  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication D/MPEG4Writer﹕ Stopping Video track
05-06 17:27:20.551  17114-17114/com.example.andreaskaitis.myapplication V/WRITE MOVIE﹕ VIDEO CREATED
```

Comment: It's generally easier (and more efficient) to use a single EGL context with two EGLSurfaces than to use two separate contexts with sharing. If you want to stick with shared contexts, make sure the first context is current when you call `prepareEncoder()` (add some log messages there to confirm). In `generateSurfaceFrame()` both of your calls to `glBindFramebuffer()` take zero as argument -- intentional? Add some logging to see if `glReadPixels()` is actually getting nonzero pixel data out.

Comment: @fadden When I log the pixelBuffer i get r=0 g=0 b=128 for all the frames. I thought the calls the 'glBindFramebuffer()' needed a 0 argument...What should it be? thanks for taking the time!

Comment: I suspect you don't want to call `glBindFramebuffer()` at all. And you seem to be reading the pixels into a variable called `pixelBuffer` which is never actually used. I expect you want to use those pixels in some sort of draw operation after you make the input surface's context current.

Comment: @fadden If it is not too much to ask can you offer some code on the draw operation? I would gladly buy you a beer or two for helping out :)

Comment: Grafika has a few examples (https://github.com/google/grafika). The TextureUploadActivity renders textures to a Surface. When working with OpenGL it's usually best to start with something trivial, like `glClear()` alternating red and blue, just to see if anything is working at all, and then work on getting fancier stuff going.  In general I think the `gles` code in Grafika is easier to work with than the stuff I threw together for the CTS tests.